# As co-founder, does Steve Jobs still own enough Apple shares to control Apple Inc.?

Tags: stocks

Steve Jobs is one of the Apple Co-founders, and as such I think he probably owns a good number of Apple's shares.

However based in his Net worth: $5.5 billion (2010) (via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs)) and the total equity
$31.64 billion (2009) of Apple (via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.)). I think he could at best own a little part from the company.

As far as I understand he is no more the Apple's owner. he should have at least the half of the company shares plus one, to have a totally authoritarian vote in the boards of directors. right?

Comment: Does Apple have Class B shares?  That's another way for him to exercise control, even if his total number of shares is not a majority.

Comment: @msemack. According to Apple's latest quarterly report they only have one class of common stock. No class B or preferred shares outstanding or authorized.

Comment: I believe he sold all his founders stock when he left the company the first time. Hence why he is not quite as rich as Bill Gates today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everyone that owns a share of stock in a company is part owner. Some just own more than others. According to Apple's latest proxy statement he owns 5.5 million shares of the 914 million shares outstanding. So he owns approximately 0.6% of the company.

If he owned more than 50% of the company's outstanding stock he would effectively control the board of directors by being able to pick whoever he wanted.  Then he would control the company. Very few publicly traded companies are that way. Most have sold off parts of the company to the public in order to raise cash for the company and make their investment more liquid.